# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundErro when running test for Android Room

Tags: android, android-room

I'm getting below exception when running test for Room.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory
```

My gradle imports

```
    //Room
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha3"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3"
androidTestCompile ("android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0-alpha3"){
    exclude module: 'gson'
}
```

clean and rebuild doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Why are you using `FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory` databse ?? `android.arch.persistence.room` have already its own database.

Comment: I'm not using it. Thats from the exception stacktrace.

Comment: But log says that you have used or imported this library in any file that can not be found in your project..

Comment: No, I'm not importing or using it anywhere in my code, it's from the Room stacktrace, it is used internally when initialise Room database for testing.

Comment: will you post your both gradle build file?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't give the error, but you can try with testCompile although testCompile by default, also includes the compiled production classes but better to give one try.

```
//Room
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha3"
testCompile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3"
androidTestCompile ("android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0-alpha3"){
    exclude module: 'gson'
}
```